# Reset of Tabulator Header Filter by selection a placeholder value

Tags: javascript, tabulator

I am using this kind of code to filter table results based on table values :

```js
{title:"Name", field:"name" headerFilter:"select", headerFilterPlaceholder:"Choose a name", headerFilterParams:{values:true}}
```

This works fine.

However I would like to add the column header filter placeholder text to the parameter list also, so that selecting the Placeholder Texts as filter value shows all values again. Selecting the placeholder value "Choose a name" should reset / remove the previous filter value and show all names again.

Anybody knows a way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

The functionality you request is not included in any of the standard header filters.

The good news is that header filters are simply editors,and you can easily build your own custom editor for the table.

Have a read through the [Custom Editor Documentation](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.7/edit#edit-custom) it will walk you step by step through building your own editor